# c# error capturing wmi

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wmi

I have the below code that goes through physical disks and displays WMI settings.

I have noticed that if a WMI parameter does not exists it does not display anything (which is fine) but this interferes with subsequent WMI parameters that DO exists on the server and they now do not show anything...even they they should..example below.

So, what I mean is that the code goes through this part:

```
 lblcapability_desc.Text = "Capability Description: " + moDisk["CapabilityDescription"].ToString();
                    lblAvailability.Text = "Availability: " + moDisk["Availability"].ToString();
                    lblbytepersector.Text = "Bytes per Sector: " + moDisk["BytesPerSector"].ToString();
                    lbl_deviceid.Text = "Device ID: " + moDisk["systemname"].ToString();
```

It first gets SystemName,
Then it gets Type and so on.

Nowthen, if on a computer the WMI parameter of say "Availability" does not exist then it will not display that. That is fine. HOWEVER, immediatly after "Availability" there is "Bytes per sector" parameter and others. The parameters of these do not display anything as well (even though I know they should show something as they do exist on the server - tested via powershell).

It is as though the lack of information from "Availability" is interfering with the parameters after and not displaying anything.

The only way I can think at the moment of fixing this (so that even if availability shows nothing but subsequent parameters show the data they need) is to possibly add a IF THEN within each WMI paramter - not nice coding but can't think of a way of fixing this.

So an exmaple would be IF [Availbility] then message "Avialbility = whatever" ELSE "WMI parameter not found". This way each WMI parameter has its own error checking. Not nice coding I imagine..

There is already an error capture in case a WMI parameter does not exist then a comment is displayed to the end user.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace diskdrive_info
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get all the disk drives
            ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisk = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
            // Loop through each object (disk) retrieved by WMI
            foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisk.Get())
            {
                cmbHdd.Items.Add(moDisk["Model"].ToString());
            }
        }

        private void cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model = '" + cmbHdd.SelectedItem + "'");
                foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
                {

                    lblSystemName.Text = "SystemName: " + moDisk["systemname"];
                    lblType.Text = "Type: " + moDisk["MediaType"].ToString();
                    lblModel.Text = "Model: " + moDisk["Model"].ToString();
                    lblCapacity.Text = "Capacity: " + moDisk["Size"].ToString() + " bytes (" + Math.Round(((((double)Convert.ToDouble(moDisk["Size"]) / 1024) / 1024) / 1024), 2) + " GB)";
                    lblPartitions.Text = "Partitions: " + moDisk["Partitions"].ToString();
                    lblSectors.Text = "Sectors: " + moDisk["SectorsPerTrack"].ToString();
                    lblSignature.Text = "Signature: " + moDisk["Signature"].ToString();
                    lblFirmware.Text = "Firmware: " +moDisk["FirmwareRevision"].ToString();
                    lblFirmware.Text = "Firmware: " + moDisk["FirmwareRevision"] == null ? "Not Available" : moDisk["FirmwareRevision"].ToString();
                    lblcapability_desc.Text = "Capability Description: " + moDisk["CapabilityDescription"].ToString();
                    lblAvailability.Text = "Availability: " + moDisk["Availability"].ToString();
                    lblbytepersector.Text = "Bytes per Sector: " + moDisk["BytesPerSector"].ToString();
                    lbl_deviceid.Text = "Device ID: " + moDisk["systemname"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                lblError.Text = "Some properties were not shown due to WMI errors or member not available on this system";
            }

        }

        private void btn_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //lblSystemName.Text = string.Empty;
            lblSystemName.Text = "SystemName: " + "";
            lblType.Text = "Type: " + "";
            lblModel.Text = "Model: " + "";
            lblCapacity.Text = "Capacity: " + "";
            lblPartitions.Text = "Partitions: " + "";
            lblSectors.Text = "Sectors: " + "";
            lblSignature.Text = "Signature: " + "";
            lblFirmware.Text = "Firmware: " + "";
            lblError.Text = String.Empty;
            cmbHdd.Items.Clear();
            cmbHdd.Text = "";
            ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisk = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
            foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisk.Get())
            {
                cmbHdd.Items.Add(moDisk["Model"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what error capturing…to mean?.Can i request you to change the wordings in your question to be more meaningful.

Comment: changed it now....see if it makes sense now..

Answer (score 2):

### The problem you're experiencing

> It is as though the lack of information from "Availability" is interfering with the parameters after and not displaying anything.

This is partially the case: "Availability" doesn't exist and a NullReferenceException is thrown.  Check to see if it is null before assigning the label (the code appears to be doing this with FirmwareRevision).

```
lblAvailability.Text = "Availability: " + moDisk["Availability"] != null ? moDisk["Availability"].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

The second part of the problem is you're wrapping the entire method body, including the iteration statement in a try-catch.  If an unhandled exception occurs in the `try` block, then execution switches to the `catch` block.

### Extra credit: simplify WMI reporting using generics & reflections

I've seen quite a few instances where WMI information is displayed in the UI directly from the WMI query objects where you see something like this a few thousand times in your UI:

```
lblName.Text = mgmtObjQuery["Name"]
```

While this does give you the desired results, there are more efficient ways of doing this that don't result in premature hair loss.  Just wait until your PM expands the requirements to include twenty more classes from root\cimv2.

I came up with a solution to get WMI information using generics, strongly typed classes, and reflection to do the heavy lifting, and now my code looks more like this:

```
lblName.Text = disk.Name;
```

First, create a model for the WMI class.  The class name and its field names should all correspond to the same WMI class names and fields.  The class & fields should be public, and the data types should also match C# data types.

Go to the [MSDN reference for Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and generate a class that looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A Win32_DiskDrive class based on 
/// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx
/// </summary>
public class Win32_DiskDrive 
{
    public UInt16 Availability;
    public UInt32 BytesPerSector;
    public UInt16[] Capabilities ;
    public string[] CapabilityDescriptions ;
    public string Caption;
    public string CompressionMethod;
    public UInt32 ConfigManagerErrorCode;
    public bool ConfigManagerUserConfig;
    public string CreationClassName;
    public UInt64 DefaultBlockSize;
    public string Description;
    public string DeviceID;
    public bool ErrorCleared;
    public string ErrorDescription;
    public string ErrorMethodology;
    public string FirmwareRevision;
    public UInt32 Index;
    public DateTime InstallDate;
    public string InterfaceType;
    public UInt32 LastErrorCode;
    public string Manufacturer;
    public UInt64 MaxBlockSize;
    public UInt64 MaxMediaSize;
    public bool MediaLoaded;
    public string MediaType;
    public UInt64 MinBlockSize;
    public string Model;
    public string Name;
    public bool NeedsCleaning;
    public UInt32 NumberOfMediaSupported;
    public UInt32 Partitions;
    public string PNPDeviceID;
    public UInt16[] PowerManagementCapabilities ;
    public bool PowerManagementSupported;
    public UInt32 SCSIBus;
    public UInt16 SCSILogicalUnit;
    public UInt16 SCSIPort;
    public UInt16 SCSITargetId;
    public UInt32 SectorsPerTrack;
    public string SerialNumber;
    public UInt32 Signature;
    public UInt64 Size;
    public string Status;
    public UInt16 StatusInfo;
    public string SystemCreationClassName;
    public string SystemName;
    public UInt64 TotalCylinders;
    public UInt32 TotalHeads;
    public UInt64 TotalSectors;
    public UInt64 TotalTracks;
    public UInt32 TracksPerCylinder;

    public Win32_DiskDrive()
    {

    }
}
```

This generic method will do the heavy lifting.  This method uses reflections to map field names to WMI query results.  Null-checking and date time conversion are all handled in a single place:

```
/// <summary>
/// Generic method that uses reflection for wiring up a local class to the corresponding win32_class and properties.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">A class who's name and fields correspond to those of a WMI class.</typeparam>
/// <returns>A collection of WMI data.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> WmiSnapshot<T>()
{
    // The name of T must match that of the WMI class
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new SelectQuery(Activator.CreateInstance<T>().GetType().Name));

    foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in searcher.Get())
    {
        // Creates an instance of T
        var listItem = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        // an array of PUBLIC FIELDS of T
        var fields = listItem.GetType().GetFields();
        // matches a value from the WMI query to a field name
        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            if (managementObject[field.Name] != null)
            {
                field.SetValue(listItem,
                    field.FieldType == typeof(DateTime)
                        ? ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(managementObject[field.Name].ToString())
                        : Convert.ChangeType(managementObject[field.Name], field.FieldType));
            }
        }
        yield return listItem;
    }
}
```

I keep my WMI classes and WMI helper methods in their own class to invoke from the UI.  The UI code is easier to read and much easier to debug.

Here is a quick sample that outputs the results of this snapshot to the console:

```
var disks = WmiHelper.WmiSnapshot<Win32_DiskDrive>().ToList(); 

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

foreach (Win32_DiskDrive disk in disks)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("SystemName: {0}\r\n", disk.SystemName);
    sb.AppendFormat("Type: {0}\r\n",  disk.MediaType);
    sb.AppendFormat("Model: {0}\r\n",  disk.Model);
    sb.AppendFormat("Capacity: {0}\r\n", disk.Size );
    sb.AppendFormat("Partitions: {0}\r\n", disk.Partitions);
    sb.AppendFormat("Sectors: {0}\r\n",  disk.SectorsPerTrack);
    sb.AppendFormat("Signature: {0}\r\n", disk.Signature);
    sb.AppendFormat("Firmware: {0}\r\n",  string.IsNullOrEmpty(disk.FirmwareRevision) ? "Not Available" : disk.FirmwareRevision);
    sb.AppendFormat("Capability Description: {0}\r\n", string.Join("\r\n", disk.CapabilityDescriptions));
    sb.AppendFormat("Availability: {0}\r\n", disk.Availability);
    sb.AppendFormat("Bytes per Sector: {0}\r\n", disk.BytesPerSector);
    sb.AppendFormat("Device ID: {0}\r\n", disk.DeviceID);
    sb.AppendLine();
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

The output looks something like this:

```
SystemName: UVVXWVXXWV
Type: Fixed hard disk media
Model: ST9500420AS
Capacity: 500105249280
Partitions: 4
Sectors: 63
Signature: 2210653369
Firmware: 0006
Capability Description: Random Access
Supports Writing
SMART Notification
Availability: 0
Bytes per Sector: 512
Device ID: \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
```

Now repeat the same for [Win32_ComputerSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then [Win32_Product](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)!

Let me know if that puts you in the right direction.

Comment: wow!! This is really good stuff Nick...especially the extra credit! This is exactly what I am after! definitely put me on the right path.  In regards to the TRY CATCH you mentioned - whats the best way of doing this? Should I get rid of the entire try catch in the method and have one per WMI field? I will figure out how I can integrate your extra credit to my code...this is quality!

Comment: Avoid putting entire method bodies in a try-catch.  Instead, identify where certain exceptions occur.  With a System.NullRefException, checking to see if a value is null before assigning will prevent that exception from occurring.  You are doing this in your code where you are handling a null value on FirmwareRevision.... lblFirmware.Text = "Firmware: " + moDisk["FirmwareRevision"] == null ? "Not Available" : moDisk["FirmwareRevision"].ToString();

Comment: If you use a try-catch, it should be specific as to the error.  Like if a managementObject value is null, it will throw a System.NullReferenceException, or if you misspell a value (e.g. "CapabilityDescription" should be "CapabilityDescriptions") you'll get a System.Management.ManagementException.  My extra credit should alleviate both instances as it checks for null values and uses the name of the field to derive the managementObject value.